# Duda sobre clases c#

Tags: c#

Tengo dos clase es una llamada `Autos` y otra `Utilitarios`. Cuando voy a buscar un vehículo por su matricula en `Autos` y esa matricula pertenece a un `Utilitario` me salta error en el codigo de abajo. Como puedo para que en vez de que se me lanze un error, yo le tire un mensaje diciendo que ese vehiculo pertenece a la clase `Utilitario`.

```
else {
      Console.WriteLine(((Utilitarios)v).MostrarPolimorfico());
      Console.WriteLine("\n" + "¿Que desea hacer?");
      Console.WriteLine("\n" + "1- EDITAR INFORMACION");
      Console.WriteLine("2- BORRAR VEHICULO");
```

Comment: Hola Puedes ponerlo dentro de un Try Cach

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: No se controlo InvalidCastException

Comment: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo Autos al tipo Utilitarios @Flxtr

Comment: Entonces se requiere que pongas la definición de las clases para ver cómo están hechas

Comment: Bastaba con hacer un try catch como dijo @PedroÁvila, muchas gracias a ambos

Comment: @Francop usar un try catch, aunque soluciona tu problema en primera medida, no seria lo ideal a futuro. si agregas la definicion de las clases, podriamos encontrar una solucion mejor. los try catch se usan para errores que no se pueden prevenir. este, se puede prevenir.

Comment: Hola deberías ser más explícito para poder entender el escenario. Muestranos tus entidades de negocio Autos, Utilitarios. Comenta un breve resumen del negocio para poder entender el problema con total claridad, asi puedes obtener mejores respuestas y más rápidas. Algo que me llama la atención es que tienes una clase Autos pero sin embargo hablas de vehículo un vehículo es algo más generalizado. Me parece hay que corregir el diseño de tu solución de negocio y después implementar el código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque obviamente `try/catch` puede resolver el problema, no es recomendable usar las excepciones para gestionar este tipo de errores. En este caso, una sencilla comprobación del tipo de la instancia usando [`is`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) bastaría y el código queda mas legible y limpio:

```
else {
  if (v is Utilitarios)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(((Utilitarios)v).MostrarPolimorfico());
      Console.WriteLine("\n" + "¿Que desea hacer?");
      Console.WriteLine("\n" + "1- EDITAR INFORMACION");
      Console.WriteLine("2- BORRAR VEHICULO");
  }
  else
  { 
      Console.WriteLine("El vehiculo no es un utilitario");
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Para poder capturar un error y personalizar el mensaje debes de poner tu código dentro de un Try Catch.

```
class MyClass 
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
      MyClass x = new MyClass();
      try 
      {
         string s = null;
         x.MyFn(s);
      }

      catch (Exception e)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
      }
   }
```

Revisa este link [Try Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.71).aspx)